# The key signatures C-flat minor and G-flat minor: do they exist?

Tags: theory, scales, sheet-music, key-signatures

Do the key signatures C-flat minor/G-flat minor exist?  If yes,what notes are used in them, and they are rarely or frequently used in classical music?

Also: DO  these keys exist 9((not theorethical) in songs with half semitone scales (i.e. xenharmonic music)?

Comment: Pretty pointless, as Bm and F#m are far easier to write, read. In 12tet, if that makes any difference.

Comment: But there also other key signatures that sound identical: D-sharp major, A-sharp major, B-sharp major, B-sharp minor, G-sharp major, e-sharp major, etc... Do you think that they should have different pitch when using a scale with more than 12 notes per octave?

Comment: @Tim they are the same in any twelve-tone temperament.  That is, the reason (for example) E♭ and D♯ are the same is that there is only one key available to serve for both.  Whether or not the distance from D to that key is the same as the distance from that key to E makes no difference.

Comment: This thread isn't really a duplicate of the aforementioned older thread. The most abstruse key the older question mentioned is A♭ minor; not only does this have a key signature (7 flats), there are real pieces which use it. By contrast, G♭ minor and C♭ minor are too abstruse for conventional key *signatures*. Even those *keys* would only be met in passing, even then only if the composer refused to do an enharmonic change (such a change would give an easier key of F# minor or B minor), and even then no such key *signature* would be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do the key signatures C-flat minor/G-flat minor exist?

Theoretically, they can be said to exist, but since these keys are the relative minor keys of E♭♭ major and B♭♭ major, respectively, the key signatures involve double flats.  They are impractical and weird.  Furthermore, they are (on any 12-tone keyboard) enharmonically equivalent to B minor and F♯ minor, respectively, so there's really no point in using them.

> If yes, what notes are used in them?

C♭ natural minor: C♭, D♭, E♭♭, F♭, G♭, A♭♭, B♭♭
C♭ harmonic minor: C♭, D♭, E♭♭, F♭, G♭, A♭♭, B♭
C♭ melodic minor (ascending): C♭, D♭, E♭♭, F♭, G♭, A♭, B♭

G♭ natural minor: G♭, A♭, B♭♭, C♭, D♭, E♭♭, F♭
G♭ harmonic minor: G♭, A♭, B♭♭, C♭, D♭, E♭♭, F
G♭ melodic minor (ascending): G♭, A♭, B♭♭, C♭, D♭, E♭, F

The descending melodic minor scales are the same as the natural minor.

> Are they rarely or frequently used in classical music?

They are certainly extremely rare in classical music.  In fact, I would be very surprised if they have ever been used at all.

Answer (score 4):

Answer for the xenharmonic part:

In *some* scales, they **definitely *do* exist**. For example, consider the 19-TET, where G♭ is a note on its own, which is different from F♯ (C♭ is also a different note, but now it's enharmonic with H♯, not H♮ as in 12-TET). So, G♭ minor and C♭ minor are "normal" keys in 19-TET, despite their key signatures have double accidentals (9 and 10 flats respectively — but since only the scales which have the same number of accidentals* modulo 19 are enharmonically equivalent in 19-TET, so in order to represent *all* 19 possible (sounding) classes of keys one has to use key signatures with at least 9 (or 10) accidentals).

*Number of accidentals is meant to be positive for sharps and negative for flats

Comment: By the way, H is the German nomenclature for B♮ in English nomenclature.